# I am writing an apex wrapper class getting errors and unable to capture the ID of the oldest record available in the child object

Tags: apex, wrapper-class

I get this compile error:

> Error is line 20 unexpected token: ':'

but can't see why. The class is:

```
public class Consent_Records_Ctrl1 {
    public date startDate{get;set;}
    public date EndDate{get;set;}
    public  long store{get;set;}
    public List<WrapConsent> allCon{get;set;}
    public List<Consent__c> allConRecs{get;set;}
    public map<string,string>MapAccAr=new map<string,string>();
    public PageReference consentFilter() {


    for (AggregateResult groupedResults: [SELECT  Count(Id)ids,Account__r.Id accids FROM Consent__c where CreatedDate >=:startDate AND LastModifiedDate <=:EndDate GROUP BY Account__r.Id]) {
       // System.debug('ID' + ar.get('ids'));
       // System.debug('Count Id' + ar.get('expr0'));
              MapAccAr.put(string.valueof(groupedResults.get('accids')),string.valueof(groupedResults.get('ids')));
    }
    for(Consent__C consent:[select account__r.id,name,Salutation__c,FirstName__c ,Initials__c,LastNamePrefix__c,LastName__c,
            ElectricityCurrentRedeliveryNum__c,ElectricityCurrentRedeliveryLowNum__c ,MeterTariffChoice__c,
            PhoneNumber__C,EmailAddress__c,Main_Street__c,Main_Number__c,Main_Addition__c,Main_PostalCode__c,
            Main_City__c,Exclude_from_Surveys__c from Consent__c where ElectricityCurrentRedeliveryNum__c > 0  and Status__c = 'Processed']
            [ CreatedDate >=:startDate AND LastModifiedDate <=:EndDate]){
               WrapConsent wrapCon=new WrapConsent();
               if(MapAccAr.containsKey(string.valueof(consent.account__r.id)))
               wrapCon.coutOfid=MapAccAr.get(string.valueof(consent.account__r.id));
               wrapCon.accid=string.valueof(consent.account__r.id);
               wrapCon.name=consent.name;
               wrapCon.Salutation=consent.Salutation__c;
               wrapCon.FirstName=consent.FirstName__c;
               wrapCon.Initials=consent.Initials__c;
               wrapCon.LastNamePrefix=consent.LastNamePrefix__c;
               wrapCon.LastName=consent.LastName__c;
               wrapCon.ElectricityCurrentRedeliveryNum=string.valueof(consent.ElectricityCurrentRedeliveryNum__c);
               wrapCon.ElectricityCurrentRedeliveryLowNum=string.valueof(consent.ElectricityCurrentRedeliveryLowNum__c);
               wrapCon.MeterTariffChoice=consent.MeterTariffChoice__c;
               wrapCon.PhoneNumber=string.valueof(consent.PhoneNumber__C);
               wrapCon.EmailAddress=consent.EmailAddress__c;
               wrapCon.Main_Street=consent.Main_Street__c;
               wrapCon.Main_Street=consent.Main_addition__c;
               wrapCon.Main_Number=string.valueof(consent.Main_Number__c);
               wrapCon.Main_PostalCode=consent.Main_PostalCode__c;
               wrapCon.Main_City=consent.Main_City__c;
               wrapCon.Exclude_from_Surveys=string.valueof(consent.Exclude_from_Surveys__c);

                }

            return null;
            return consentFilter();
        }
        public List<WrapConsent> getConsentlist() {
        return allCon;
        }

    public void ConsentDisplay()
        {
            if(startDate!=NULL&&EndDate!=NULL)
            {
                if(startDate!=NULL&&EndDate!=NULL)
                {              
                    store=1;
                }
                else
                {
                    store=0;
                }
            }

        }
        public class WrapConsent{
        public string coutOfid{set;get;}
        public string accid{set;get;}
        public string name{set;get;}
        public string Salutation{set;get;}
        public string FirstName{set;get;}
        public string Initials{set;get;}
        public string LastNamePrefix{set;get;}
        public string LastName{set;get;}
        public string ElectricityCurrentRedeliveryNum{set;get;}
        public string ElectricityCurrentRedeliveryLowNum{set;get;}
        public string MeterTariffChoice{set;get;}
        public string PhoneNumber{set;get;}
        public string EmailAddress{set;get;}
        public string Main_Street{set;get;}
        public string Main_Number{set;get;}
        public string Main_PostalCode{set;get;}
        public string Main_City{set;get;}
        public string Exclude_from_Surveys{set;get;}
        public string Main_addition{set;get;}

    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Change the **soql** your passing inside for loop. You have messed up with **square bracket** near where clause.

```
for(Consent__C consent:[select account__r.id, name,Salutation__c, FirstName__c,
                        Initials__c,LastNamePrefix__c,LastName__c,
                        ElectricityCurrentRedeliveryNum__c, ElectricityCurrentRedeliveryLowNum__c , 
                        MeterTariffChoice__c,PhoneNumber__C,EmailAddress__c,Main_Street__c,Main_Number__c, 
                        Main_Addition__c, Main_PostalCode__c,
                        Main_City__c,Exclude_from_Surveys__c from Consent__c 
                        where ElectricityCurrentRedeliveryNum__c > 0  and Status__c = 'Processed'
                        CreatedDate >=:startDate AND LastModifiedDate <=:EndDate])
```

Comment: Can you add to this answer detail of what you have changed and perhaps rephrase to say "Change" not "Check"?

Comment: Still a bit hard to see the change but +1 from me.

Comment: @KeithC Thank You...

Comment: Thank you Nitesh can you help me display the oldest consent__c.ID as well on the report.

Comment: Oldest consent__C.ID in term of what condition your telling?.  Already you are fetching Consent__c based on "CreatedDate >=:startDate " this condition. Oldest means  you wanted fetch "Consent__c"  based on "CreatedDate <=:startDate this condition.

Comment: If I need to be more precise this is a report that is being fetched between startdate & Enddate. In this the records that are being seen in screen are for the newest record added but i also need to see the oldest record details in this screen only four values like -- Oldest consent ID, name, ElectricityCurrentRedeliveryNum & ElectricityCurrentRedeliveryLowNum

Comment: write SOQL to get  consent ID, name, ElectricityCurrentRedeliveryNum & ElectricityCurrentRedeliveryLowNum with "order by CreatedDate desc" clause  with  limit 4.

Comment: I am unable to display the records using this code some thing is wrong can this be fixed for me

Comment: can u update your code, What you have tried

Comment: I have answered what you missed in your updated Question